# Cannot send a confirmation email through google forms

Tags: javascript, forms, google-forms

I am trying to integrate this to a form we are using. As you can see I am using this code to send an email to whoever submit the form. However, I do get the error that var `emailTo = e.namedValues[2].toString();` has the error of

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined (line 5,
>   file "Code")"

```
function sendEmail(e) {

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("htmlemail.html")
  var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();
  var emailTo = e.namedValues[2].toString(); //column B is for the email

  var subject = "Thanks for participation";
  var textBody = "This email requires HTML support. Please make sure you open with a client that supports it."
  var options = { htmlBody : htmlText };

  if (emailTo!== undefined){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, textBody, options)
  }
}
```

Note that column B in the spread sheet is where the email should be filled.

Comment: Where are you calling `sendEmail()`? Looks like whatever you're passing in as the `e` parameter isn't what you think it is (or anything at all, for that matter).

Comment: I am not a programmer and this is my first time trying to do this. What I am trying to do is to make the script read the email entered in the google forms and then send a confirmation email.